# Losing elements in list of tuples during Recursion and Guards not picking up on condition

Tags: haskell

I have a problem whereby I have a database consisting of a list of tuples relating to the storage of a song, artist, and sales figure. I have to iterate through the list using the songName and artistName, and if these are within the database I must increment the sales value by one and output this along with the other tuples within the database. If the songName and artistName are not within the database I must output the tuples within the database along with a new tuple containing the entered songName, artistName, and first sale, e.g.
`[("Heartbeat","Kelly Clarkson",7), ("Rise","The Shadows",15), ("Hello", "Adele", 1)]`.

My solution to the problem is below:

```
testData :: [Sales]
testData = [ ("No Lie", "Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa",  100)
           , ("Yes Lie", "Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa",  10)
           , ("Fear & Delight", "The Correspondents",  120) ]



recordSale :: [Sales] -> String -> String-> [Sales]

recordSale [dataSet] trackName artistName = [(trackName, artistName, 1)]
recordSale ((track, artist, qty): xs) trackName artistName 
     | track == trackName && artist == artistName = xs ++ [(track, artist, qty + 1)]
     | otherwise = recordSale xs trackName artistName
     | track /= trackName && artist /= artistName = xs ++ [(track, artist, 1)]
```

I have written a recursive function with guards to try and find the songName and artistName within the dataset however I have a weird unexpected output.

When entering data I have weird output. If I was to enter `recordSale testData "Yes Lie" "Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa"` the program would output `[("Fear & Delight","The Correspondents",120),("Yes Lie","Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa",11)]`. Accept for the expected missing element issue described in Problem 1, this is expected.

However, if I were to enter `recordSale testData "Fear & Delight" "The Correspondents"`, I would get the unusual behaviour or being returned `[("Fear & Delight","The Correspondents",1)]`. Given this song is within the database, I would have expected the sales figure to increment by 1.

Given that the song was only outputted and not the song attached to the list, I think this might be caused by my base case `recordSale [dataSet] trackName artistName = [(trackName, artistName, 1)]` but i'm not 100% sure on that

How do I go about returning a song which isn't on the list with the sale of 1, and stop successful queries returning 1 for their sales when they are included within the database?

EDIT:

Replaced `recordSale [dataSet] trackName artistName = []` with `recordSale [dataSet] trackName artistName = [(trackName, artistName, 1)]` to more accurately reflect the issue I am having with Problem 2.

EDIT 2: Edited the wording of problem 2 so that it is more 'readable'.

EDIT 3: Reduced post to one question.

Comment: Are you sure you want the clause `recordSale [dataSet] trackName artistName = []`? You know what this does, right?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Not really. From the limited knowledge I have, i'm guessing it returns an empty list when I  enter the trackName and artistName. Is my understanding correct? When I have this in my code I would get `warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns]
    Pattern match is redundant`

Comment: A guard under the `otherwise` does not make much sense, since `otherwise` is an alias for `True` and will thus always fire.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I wasn't sure if I could have a guard under otherwise. I did have the guard above otherwise before. However, the program kept outputting the list with the first tuple having sales of 1 rather than 100. So the program wasn't hitting the recursive case

Comment: [mcve] please, with emphasis on minimal. one specific test call please, one question about it. you can always post more questions, each focused on its one specific narrow problem. easier to answer, more rep. points for you. a win-win. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.  The first is in the guard

```
     | otherwise = recordSale xs trackName artistName
     | track /= trackName && artist /= artistName = xs ++ [(track, artist, 1)]
```

What happens is that when the pair `trackName` and `artistName` is not an exact match, the list is truncated because you only pass on `xs`.  The second line that handles the exact mismatch will never be hit because patterns are ordered and `otherwise` is a catch-all.  (The implementation is wrong anyway because it appends a new element whenever the current element doesn't match)

The other problem is in the pattern

```
recordSale [dataSet] trackName artistName = [(trackName, artistName, 1)]
```

This matches when the list only has a single element, but what if that element is a match?  Currently this case is ignored and the count is simply set to 1.

Hence I would propose the following:

<sup>(I also replaced list concatenation `++` by list construction `:` because it saves some typing and removes a bit of clutter)</sup>

```
type Sales = (String, String, Int)

testData :: [Sales]
testData = [ ("No Lie", "Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa",  100)
           , ("Yes Lie", "Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa",  10)
           , ("Fear & Delight", "The Correspondents",  120) ]

recordSale :: [Sales] -> String -> String-> [Sales]
recordSale [] trackName artistName = [(trackName, artistName, 1)]
recordSale ((track, artist, qty): xs) trackName artistName 
     | track == trackName && artist == artistName = (track, artist, qty + 1) : xs
     | otherwise = (track, artist, qty) : recordSale xs trackName artistName
```

In the `otherwise` clause I do not discard the current element but construct a list with the recursive rest.  The other important change is the base case.  Instead of matching a list with one element, I match the empty list and return a list with the new item inserted.

[Live example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7mhNJgt9tlDPCCGA)